# font in iphone gives an image

Tags: iphone, email, fonts

I have added the character  after my name in my adress email. On Gmail or Ubuntu, it appears indeed as a . But people that read my emails on iphone get a small boar head!!

From what I read on Internet, iphone is using by default Helvetica font. And the tick is not a boar in this font.

Does anyone know where this could come from??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a friend about your icon issue and he had me look into a popular emoticon plugin for iOS devices. Sure enough, after browsing through the icons, there was the small boar's head you are talking about.

The plugin is called Emoji and it essentially adds an extra keyboard to iOS Messages app. It's a possibility that the users who have reported this issue to you have that plugin installed on their devices? This might be where the icon is coming from. Let me know if you need any more information on this problem. I hope you are able to solve it!

Comment: Thanks it seems this is the reason indeed! Apple is natively supporting some emoticons of this library
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Apple_Encoding